# Get a <input> button to carry a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a little program for tradeshows we are doing. 
It is spitting out a block for each tradeshow with information about it.

I want to add an "Edit"-button in each block, to take me to a page where I can edit that specific tradeshow.

How can I get the Edit-button to bring along the ID for that block?

If I make the Value $id then I can bring it, but because value is also the label on the button it says a number (the id) instead of Edit, which isn't pretty.

Can someone give me a hand? :)

Comment: Can you post some code? A sample block including your Edit button would be great.

Comment: Post a little bit of code, specifically your <input> or <button>, and that would make it a little more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I get the reason why you want to POST that value. Wouldn't be easier just using links and getting the ID via GET?

Comment: @cbrandolino an "edit" doesn't sound much like "getting". Don't abuse GET. http://tomayko.com/writings/on-http-abuse

Comment: Uh, so you think they are different forms? now i got it. I thought about something to bring you to the edit page for each entry.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap each button in a form, like this:

```
<form action="/edit/42"><button type="submit">Edit</button></form>
```

Don't forget to use appropriate CSS styling for the new form element.

You can also attach any behavior you want with JavaScript. Store the ID in a data attribute, like this:

```
<button data-edit-id="42">Edit</button>
// In JavaScript (with jQuery)
$('button').click(function(ev) {
    location.href = '/edit/' + $(ev.target).attr('data-edit-id');
});
```

Comment: +1 For nicer REST design. If you are editing the item with `id=42` of course you should send your request to an url ending in `/42`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a form for each block (if it isn´t already there...) and add a hidden field with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use the button's click event to set the id into a hidden field and then submit the form.

Another way is to have every button in a different form, with each one having a different action (corresponding to the item to be edited). It may not be applicable depending on your markup.

Answer (score 0):

I usually abuse the `name` for it:

```
 <input type="submit" name="edit[123]" value="edit">
```

Receiving code:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $id = key($_POST['edit']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to use a button in this case. I think you should include a clickable icon that points to the edit form. From what I can tell is that your information blocks are in `<form>` format for reasons unknown when they should be in a table or set of neatly aligned divs.

I would suggest you create a link and on the other page use `$_GET['id']` to edit that entry:

```
<a href="/edit/?id=<?php echo $tradeshowID; ?>"><img src="/icons/edit.png"></a>
```

Or do I not understand the purpose of the button in your question?